# Bash/sed: Concat multiple line plus eat up leading spaces for sublines

Tags: bash, sed, concatenation

I want to parse Makefiles containing lines like these:

```
FILES=file1.c \
      file2.c \
      file3.c \
```

Now I want to parse that beast to get a result like this:

```
FILES=file1.c file2.c file3.c
```

Means it should concat all line to one line and eat up the leading spaces.
I already managed to concat the lines by using this sed call:

```
sed -e ':loop;/\\$/N;s/\\\n/ /;t loop'
```

which results in

```
FILES=file1.c      file2.c      file3.c
```

But yet did not manage to also eat up the leading spaces for line 2 and line 3 of my example.

Thanks for any help,

Roland

BTW: I am using GNU sed version 4.1.5 here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work for me:

```
sed -e ':loop;/\\$/N;s/\\\n/ /;t loop' -e 's/ \+/ /g' < Makefile
```

Thanks to [Dennis Williamson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/26428/dennis-williamson) for pointing out that you don't need `-r` if you escape the `+` with `\`.  He also notes that this doesn't work when the last character before the end of the file is `\`.  However, that's unlikely in a real example, since there's no point in doing line continuation if there's nothing afterwards.  e.g. it works fine with:

```
FILES=file1.c \
      file2.c \
      file3.c
```

...  instead.

I've only tested this with GNU sed 4.2.1 - I'm afraid I don't have an earlier version to hand.

Comment: This prematurely exits from the script when `N` reads EOF and the substitution of the spaces never gets done. You can omit the `-r` and escape the plus sign.

Comment: @Dennis Williamson: it works fine for me with all the example files I've tried - can you suggest one on which it fails?  Thanks for the tip about `-r` and `\+`...

Comment: Yours only appears to fail when the input is literally like the example in the question where the backslash also appears on the last line in the file (which would be an unusual situation). Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Ah! Somehow I'd removed the final `\\` when copying the example :)  I'll add a note about that to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
sed -e ':loop;/\\$/N;s/\\\n/ /;s/ \+/ /g;t loop'
```

The extra `s/ \+/ /g` finds all sequence of multiple spaces on a line, and substitutes them with a single space.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Infortunately it does not work here. (I already tried similar statements). I am using GNU sed version 4.1.5 on linux. When I try your statement it loops endlessly (for some reason).

Comment: @Roland: The reason it loops endlessly is that the space substitution is always successful (because it matches **one** or more) and satisfies the `t` conditional branch. Changing from one space to two like this: `s/  \+/ /g` or doing this: `s/ \{2,\}/ /g` fixes the problem.

Comment: Hrm, that's weird. For some reason it worked find on my machine. What Dennis said makes sense though so now I'm not sure why it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Ruby(1.9+)

```
ruby -ne '$_.gsub!(/\\\n/,""); print $_.gsub(/\s+/," ")' file
```

Comment: OP asked for a bash or sed script. An answer that may require a new dependency to be installed does not help.

Comment: @mkb, you are ridiculous. In a bash system, there are tools like Perl, Python and Ruby at one's disposal, besides just bash and sed. If OP is able to use them, then my solution is fine. If not, he can also leave it be. Although i cannot stop you from down voting, but please try not to be too narrow minded next time.

Comment: The type of system this is running and the freedom to install new dependencies is unspecified in the question. It's more helpful to answer the question as asked.

Comment: @mkb, its not really unspecified. We can take an educated guess as to what type of system OP is using because he did say he is using GNU sed and bash. Most likely candidate is a linux system. But whatever it is, we are all free to post suitable solutions that solves the problem and is not totally out of line/topic. If I post a solution in Linux assembly language, you can down vote all you want.

Answer (score 0):

Squeezing white space is most easily accomplished by piping your output to tr:

```
... | tr -s ' '
```

In this case, this (probably) won't work because the leading whitespace is likely tabs, so you can do:

```
... | tr '\t' ' ' | tr -s ' '
```

or just do the entire thing in perl:

```
perl -00 -pe 's/\s*\\\n\s*/ /sg'
```

This compresses all whitespace around a line continuation to a single space, so excess whitespace away from the newline will not be changed and blank lines following a continuation character will be consumed, which is probably not desirable.  Also, slurp mode is not always appropriate, so perhaps you'd prefer:

```
perl -wpe 's/^\s*// if $v; $v = s/\s*\\\n/ /g'
```